# Laravel use query builder to create rows from a date range

Tags: php, mysql, database, laravel

I have an **Event** model, that has **EventDates**

An **EventDate** has a *from* and *to* field.
In my dashboard, if an event spans multiple days, I need to show a row for each day that event exists, using the query builder so we can paginate and limit on the result set.

*Event.php*

```php
public function dates()
{
    return $this->hasMany(EventDate::class);
}
```

*This is how the data is stored in EventDate*

```
+----+------------+------------+
| id |    from    |     to     |
+----+------------+------------+
|  1 | 09-20-2019 | 09-25-2019 |
+----+------------+------------+
```

*This is how I would like to receive the data*

```
+----+------------+
| id |    date    |
+----+------------+
|  1 | 09-20-2019 |
|  1 | 09-21-2019 |
|  1 | 09-22-2019 |
|  1 | 09-23-2019 |
|  1 | 09-24-2019 |
|  1 | 09-25-2019 |
+----+------------+
```

#### Method to retrieve from a collection

I can use this method to build a result from the collection, **however this is already deriver from the results, so I can't paginate or limit on this.**

*EventDate.php*

```php
public function getRecurringAttribute()
{
    $dates = collect();
    $this->upcoming()->get()->map(function ($upcomingDate) use ($dates) {
        $period = CarbonPeriod::create($upcomingDate->date_from, $upcomingDate->date_until);
        if (!$period->count()) {
            return $upcomingDate;
        }
        foreach ($period as $date) {
            $upcomingDate->date_from = $date;
            $upcomingDate->date_until = $date;
            $dates->push($upcomingDate);
        }
        return true;
    });

    return $dates;
}
```

So I'm wondering, is it possible to achieve this result using the Query Builder? So I can paginate, limit, use scopes on the result set that is generated.

Comment: Use LengthAwarePaginator to paginate the dates you have mapped.

Comment: Store dates as dates, using a date data type.

Comment: Use LengthAwarePaginator or bad idea is insert those into temp table and you can easy use eloquent paginator.

Comment: @SagarGautam This won't allow me to futher filter them down using query builder methods, once I get the collection, it's final.

Comment: @Strawberry This is the second time you comment with useless brabble. I know how to store dates, what I'm looking for is a way to customise or extend the query builder to split rows up.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution using the following library
https://github.com/staudenmeir/laravel-cte/. This library allows the writing of CTE functions using either the Query Builder or the Model.

```php
public function scopeRecurringDates($query)
{
    return $query->from('t')
        ->withRecursiveExpression('t', "
            SELECT id, event_id, date_from as date_from, date_from as date_until, date_until as du, time_from, time_until FROM event_dates
            UNION ALL
            SELECT id, event_id, DATE_ADD(t.date_from, INTERVAL 1 DAY), DATE_ADD(t.date_from, INTERVAL 1 DAY), du, time_from, time_until
            FROM t WHERE DATE_ADD(date_from, INTERVAL 1 DAY) <= du
        ");
}
```

In my Controller I call this method by using

```php
$query = EventDate::recurringDates()
```